# How do I start a tmux service in the user's directory on user login using systemd

Tags: linux, service, systemd, tmux

I'm trying to set up my system so that when a user logs in, a `tmux` session will automatically be created for them, and this session is restarted if it ever exits, and the session starts in the user's home directory. I would like this to work for any user, or any new user added to the system, without a static unit file for each user. I'm having trouble making this work in a generic way, because I need to specify `User` and `WorkingDirectory` in the unit file for the `tmux` session to be created for the correct user in the correct directory.

So far my unit file looks like the following:

```
/etc/systemd/system/tmux-session-service.service...
---------------------------------------------------

[Unit]
Description=Tmux Session Service

[Service]
Type=forking
User=my-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/my-user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s tmux-session-service -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t tmux-session-service
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I install and enable this, everything works like I expect as long as I am logged is as `my-user`. However if I log in as another user, the `tmux` session isn't created with the right permissions or working directory for the new user.

I looked into template files, but I can't quite get things to work. I tried setting the target to `default.target`, and using the %u template directive, but that seems to just refer to the user running the service manager, which is `root`.

One option would be to run `systemctl run tmux-session-service@new-user.service` when `new-user` logs in. Then I could use `%i` in the `User` and `WorkingDirectory` directives in the unit file. But then I need some process that has systemctl permissions to kick that off on user login, and I can't think of a way to do that.

I'm running:

- Arch Linux
- tmux v3.1c
- systemd v247

Answer (score 0):

Under Ubuntu, I install the `....service` file under:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/user/...
```

With the Debian packager, that is not automatic if you installed using the .service in the `debian` installation folder. Instead, you have to do it *manually* so it goes in the correct folder. So say you have a project defined like so:

```
tmux-session-service/debian/tmux-session-service.docs
tmux-session-service/debian/tmux-session-service.install
tmux-session-service/debian/tmux-session-service.service   <-- wrong!
```

Then for each user I would enable the service like so:

```
# Make sure the target folder exists
mkdir -p /home/${USER}/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants

# If you're root when doing that, you want to fix the ownership
# (for the group, you may need a different variable)
chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /home/${USER}/.config/systemd

# If already installed, remove the link before re-creating it
rm -f /home/${USER}/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/${SERVICE}.service

# Again, I do this as root, so I need to use special care to run the
# following command as $USER isntead
sudo -H -u ${USER} sh -c "ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/user/${SERVICE}.service /home/${USER}/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/${SERVICE}.service"
```

If you want (can) do it manually, then install the file under `/usr/lib/systemd/user/...` as mentioned above, and then use the `enable` option:

```
systemctl --user enable ${SERVICE}.service
```

The problem with this technique is that you need to log in as each user to order to enable your service.

I think there is a way to have a service auto-start for all users, but that I haven't found out how to make it work yet...

Answer (score -1):

Could it be as simple as putting something in new user's .bashrc files (or in the  /etc/profile file to get a system wide effect) that attaches to a tmux session called 'main' (this would create it if it doesn't already exist)?

That's what I have in mine, and it's as if tmux is just a built in feature of my terminal:

```
# Launch tmux
if command -v tmux>/dev/null; then
    [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [ -z $TMUX ] && tmux new-session -A -s main
fi
```